# AntiVirus Software - Potential security risk?

Tags: security

I have been wondering is running an Anti-Virus Software with a Firewall brings a security risk with it while using Tor.

I recently read about a free Anti-Virus software sold its Users browsing data. Is there a way such a usually helpful software can bring harm in terms of security?

Comment: I think you answered your own question. Also, anti-virus and firewall are very different things: do you mean to refer to one or both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Any software on your machine that can access the internet has the potential to give away your information. It doesn't matter if it's an antivirus, a game, or even a professional application suite.

AFAIK Windows doesn't have anything like AppArmor that would say "This program can do A, B, and C; but if it tries to do anything else it will be blocked." So there's nothing stopping a rogue program from doing bad things.

This is why something like Tails is very good for anonymity if you are not allowed to install a more secure OS on your machine. It may be a little slower and you might want to buy a fast USB stick but you can much more peace of mind when you need to be anonymous.